# Screen is splitting: hardware or software problem?

Tags: linux-mint, hardware

I've been a Mint 19 user for some months. Beginning a couple of months ago or so my screen started getting split occasionally when I turned my computer on (see pictures). This issue was solved simply restarting my 10-year-old up-to-now-problem-free laptop. However, since yesterday the issue has been almost persistent, so even after restarting my computer several times I still get a split screen (earlier today I had to restart the machine ten times until the screen got right, and as I write this I still have a split screen). So my question is: could this be a software issue having any relation to Mint? or, is this a hardware problem?

The reason why I suspect Mint is that this issue started after I installed Mint 19 and since the beginning I've had random issues with this distro. On the other hand, the reason I suspect the laptop is its age and those nasty lines dividing the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.[image: My Screen]

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if the problem is hardware or software related is to insert a live USB stick of any other distribution in the laptop and boot in that OS, if the lines are still there then it is a hardware issue and vice versa.